# azure table export Timestamp value is not working

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-table-storage, azure-data-factory

I am trying to set up a simple data factory pipeline with intention of copying Azure table storage to Cosmos DB.
Azure table storage has a system managed field, Timestamp. When flow runs and Cosmos db is populated with the data Timestamp is always   "Timestamp": "1970-01-01T00:00:00Z". Seems that it is not getting into Cosmos DB correctly.

How to reproduce: create a Azure table, add a few entries. Create Cosmos db instance and a new collection. Create Dat Factory flow. Note how Timestamp looks when exported.

I tried to change Timestamp data type from DateTime to DateTimeOffset as well as exporting it as a string. I also tried to specify the date format. The result is the same.

I suspect that Timestamp is a reserved word in Cosmos DB and somehow it fails to insert correct value.

Answer (score 2):

I reproduced your issue on my side. I tried to add an property `time` and set the value as same as `Timestamp`. It could imported into cosmos db correctly.

[image]

So, I think it's related to field name ,not data type or data format. However, I tried to specify target column field name `timestamp` instead of `Timestamp` then it does't working.

Based on this doc, `_ts` is auto-generated by cosmos db which as a number representing the number of elapsed seconds since January 1, 1970. It logs [last updated timestamp of the resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-resources#system-vs-user-defined-resources) so that it has the same meaning as Timestamp in Azure Table storage.It could be converted `UnixDateTimeConverter` class. So,you could trace date log via `_ts` field.

If you do want keep Timestamp, you could add a property as same value sa Timestamp then import it into cosmos db.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks for trying. When failed, did you also get 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z as result?

Comment: @borys86 Sure,as same as you!

Comment: Hi Jay, so in your experiment, time is copyed successfully, but Timestamp doesn’t, right? It is related to azure table field name, not related to cosmos dB field name?

Comment: @FangLiu Hi, Timestamp is auto-generated by azure table and it clashes with 
 _ts field in cosmosdb.

Comment: as Jay points out I suspect that is something with the timestamp. It seems that in Cosmos DB Timestamp is a reserved keyword.

Comment: @borys86 yes, I totally agree with you. So, could you drop Timestamp and log _ts field in the future?